# ssh/putty binds to wrong networkcard

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

I'm using FreeSSH on my server and Putty on my client.

I'm trying to make a port (3333) on my server connect to my local PC. This way my PC port is visible to the outside.

However, when I look with netstat -an on the server, I see that there is a connection on: 127.0.0.1:3333   instead of on 0.0.0.0:3333 (or even my specific ip).

This makes the port unreachable from the outside.
Is there any way/setting to make it bind to the correct network card (or any network)

Answer (score 1):

I found it. In Putty, under Connection->SSH->tunnels, you have to both check both the checkmarks:

```
 - local ports accept connections from other hosts
 - remote ports do the same
```

I also had to restart FreeSSH. But then we I reconnected with putty it was bound to: 0.0.0.0:3333

Answer (score 0):

Normally applications have a configuration setting for that. OpenSSH has:

```
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Although, I think I misunderstand your question, reading it again. Could you clarify? Are you setting up a tunnel?

Comment: yes I'm setting up a tunnel.